# Computer randomly shuts off and loses wifi connection frequently

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, freeze, desktop, reboot

I have a `DT ASUS M32AD-US032S RT` desktop and over the last couple of months my internet connection goes in and out, as frequently as every minute or two.

Then occasionally, the computer restarts on its own without being prompted to. Sometimes if the internet connection is out, the computer projects a buzzing noise (out of the speakers) and freezes and then restarts (rare event).

Does anyone know what could be causing this or what I can check/replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with my laptop a few months back but without the the wifi disconnect issue . I drove me crazy as I was training with it and it was my laptop doing the presentation. The buzzing sound I am not sure could be the fan . If it is the fan then your fault is simple your laptop is over heating . Test this yourself check the temperature just before it restarts . Try using an application that stresses the pc eg benchmarking software and see it restarts . Also test with cpuz it shows the temperature of the cpu.  What it means is that your thermal paste requires to be replaced . Get a technician to help with this.

Comment: So, if it is overheating, simply replace the fan inside? This is a desktop btw. Could any of it have to do with the power supply by chance?

Comment: Not the power supply .  Their is a secondary fan that sits on-top of the processor it has a paste  in-between that helps with heat transfer if it dries up you get overheating issues. The processor itself initiates the shut down without the telling the OS about it thus you get no error .